# Converting an emoji code point to it's shortcut text

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I'm working on a new project and it includes allowing the user to select an emoji from a popup window using the Twemoji project for the emojis. What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to get the shortcut text of the emoji. I have access to the url in this fashion https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/14.0.2/72x72/1f605.png and I can also convert it to unicode if I need to.

For instance, I want to convert  to :smiley:

I can do it server side (classic asp) or client side (vanilla js or jquery).

Edit: I found a json file that I'm going to import into a database table and do a lookup.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamcal/emoji-data/master/emoji.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up importing this json file into a local lookup database table. Works for my purpose, might help somebody else too.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamcal/emoji-data/master/emoji.json

Answer (score 1):

There isn't just a built-in way that you'll be able to convert an emoji to something like that. As far as anything is concerned, those are just characters the same as "A" or "!".

The only way to do something like this would be to find or create a library or dictionary which you can look them up.

It looks like the filename part of that URL (`1f605`) is the [Unicode value](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), so you can feed that into a library.

Normally I'd recommend a library, but flipping through the existing options, none of them really have enough regular usage for me to be comfortable even mentioning one. I'd suggest searching NPM for "emoji" and flipping through the options and see which one you like the best / suits your needs the best.

Comment: Ya, I've come to the same conclusion so far. I found one web API to do it, but it isn't allowing new applications to use it anymore. I'll keep looking. I really don't want to create my own database with a lookup to convert them, but maybe i'll just make one with the top 50 or so emoji shortcodes. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Unless you really need it as text, you could always just store the Unicode value itself directly in the text. The emoji might look slightly different depending which device they access it on, but that may or may not be important based on your usage.

Comment: It's not 100% required to be text, but it's on the list of features they want if possible. We are wanting to allow people to select an emoji reaction to a post and then show the number of times that emoji was clicked and the tooltip would show the names of the people who selected that emoji and the shortcode name of it like "reacted with :airplane:". I think this json file can be imported into a db and solve my problem.    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamcal/emoji-data/master/emoji.json